# Which Spring initializer is preferred?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm studying Spring MVC. Help me figure out, in which cases

`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`,

`AbstractContextLoaderInitializer`,

`AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer`,

`AbstractReactiveWebInitializer`

are used for initialization. There is no detailed description of what each class is for in the documentation.

Comment: Preferably you don't touch _any_ of them and you use Spring Boot, which wires all of this up magically for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` "register a DispatcherServlet and use Java-based Spring configuration." [[1]](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html)

`AbstractContextLoaderInitializer` "register a ContextLoaderListener in the servlet context." [[2]](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.html)

`AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer` "register a DispatcherServlet in the servlet context." [[3]](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.html)

`AbstractReactiveWebInitializer` "installs a Spring Reactive Web Application on a Servlet container." [[4]](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/adapter/AbstractReactiveWebInitializer.html)

`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` extends `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer` which extends `AbstractContextLoaderInitializer`.

If you really need to implement any of these classes, you should start by the most concrete one (`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`), and only implement a parent if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw this description in the docs, but it is incomprehensible for me. How AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer differs from AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer? AbstractContextLoaderInitializer sets up the application context, but other initializers do the same. I don't understand.

Comment: Updated the answer.